# How to define log4j2 path by application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2

I want to have different `log4j2` log directories based on the current active profile. But it does not work.

```
#application.properties:
spring.profiles.active=dev
log.path=d:/${spring.profiles.active}

#log4j2.xml:
<Properties>
  <property name="path">${bundle:application:log.path}</property>
</Properties>
```

Result: a folder is created on d:/ called `${spring.profiles.active}` instead of resolving to the real spring profile name. Why?

Comment: Checkout  [Log4j's System Properties Lookup](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it as follows:
log4j2.xml:
`${main:spring.profiles.active}`

```
MainMapLookup.setMainArguments(new String[] {"spring.profiles.active", "dev"});
SpringApplication.run(source, args);
```

You can get the vmargs as follows, and set the profile dynamically before running the spring app:
`ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments()`

---

Or even better, coming back to this after years:
use `${sys:spring.profiles.active}`, as any arguments given with `-D` count as SystemProperties. You don't need the `MainMapLookup` in this case.

---

As an alternative: just logging to the classpath `logs` dir, and setting a soft link inside the execution directory, eg `ln -s /var/log logs` to redirect the log directory by the running system.

Answer (score 1):

> Result: a folder is created on `d:/` called `${spring.profiles.active}`
>   instead of resolving to the real spring profile name. Why?

There's no relation between log4j2 and Spring. The placeholder you have in your `application.properties` is for Spring to parse and replace. Log4j2 is not aware of it.

Comment: Hm, so is there any other chance I could derive my loging path by spring profile property?

Comment: @membersound There might be some integration possible, but none that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logging.config to set log4j2 path in application.yaml, like

```
---
spring:
   profiles: test
logging.config: classpath:log4j2.test.yaml
---
spring:
   profiles: online
logging.config: classpath:log4j2.online.yaml
```

with log4j2.test.yaml and log4j.online.yaml, you can set different log4j2 config in different env.

Comment: This doesn't works . If I specify logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml in application.properties and logging.config=classpath:log4j2-local.xml in application-local.properties and I start app with -Dspring.profiles.active:local . It still looks for log4j2.xml instead of log4j2-local.xml .