# How to configure log4j write to file only in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

Is that possible with one config?

1. log4j write log to file only when we run project as:java -jar project.jar &
2. log4j write log to file and print on console when we run project in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701226/5695673), which seems to describe the same problem.

By using different Spring's profiles, you can switch from one configuration to another very easily, with multiple `application.properties` files which contains the property `logging.config` pointing on different `log4j` config files.

An other option is to use the default Spring Boot's logging mechanism, `Logback` which allows you to use the `<springProfile>` tag. See [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/profile-logback-logging-config.html) for more details.