# why I can't use springProfile tag in log4j2-spring.xml to config log4j2 with different spring profiles?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

Well, I have 3 spring profiles: dev, prod, test, and I want to use different log4j2 configuration in different profiles.
I checked the the [spring-boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_profile_specific_configuration) and followed the way it said.
But when I run spring application, I only get the log below:

```
2018-03-05 09:52:32,194 main ERROR Error processing element SpringProfile ([Configuration: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2018-03-05 09:52:32,194 main ERROR Error processing element SpringProfile ([Configuration: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
```

I googled and stackoverflowed the error log, and can't still find an answer why `springProfile` tag didn't work.

And here is my `log4j2-spring.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration>
    <SpringProfile name="prod">
        <Appenders>
            <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                         fileName="/home/prod/service.log"
                         filePattern="/home/prod/service.log.%d{yyyyMMddHH}"
                         append="true">
                <PatternLayout pattern="[%level][%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX}][%l] %msg%n" />
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                </Policies>
            </RollingFile>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="INFO">
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </SpringProfile>

    <SpringProfile name="!prod">
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="[%level][%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX}][%l] %msg%n" />
            </Console>

            <File name="File" fileName="./logs/service.log" append="false">
                <PatternLayout pattern="[%level][%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX}][%l] %msg%n" />
            </File>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="INFO">
                <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
                <!--When WIP, you could uncomment the next line to show log to console.-->
                <!--<AppenderRef ref="Console"/>-->
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </SpringProfile>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Your going to get an answer with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559824/spring-profiles-different-log4j2-configs tbh

Comment: I know that [Spring Profiles, different Log4j2 configs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559824/spring-profiles-different-log4j2-configs) solves my question, but it's not elegant and not recommended by spring-boot. So here am I to ask for help.

Comment: In https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-boot/ Log4J2 says it is working with the mentioned tag. I guess this maybe not supported out of the box by Spring Boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the dependency for Log4J2's spring boot support in your project. You need to add *org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-spring-boot*. Adding this as dependency enables the usage of the `SpringProfile` tag. (This feature is available since version *2.15.0*)

One might consider this a bug of the Spring Boot Log4J2 integration.

Comment: To be historically accurate, the `SpringProfile` arbiter appeared in version 2.15.0 (see [LOG4J2-3226](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3226)) and was not available at the time this question was asked.

Comment: Okay, I was missing that bit of information here. Thanks for adding that @Pior.

Answer (score 0):

There's no relationship ([or at least not that I know](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/)) between Apache Log4J2 and the Spring Framework.

The `SpringProfile` tag you've used doesn't exist in the Log4J2's XML schema either.

You would have *to play* with different Spring Profile configurations and different Log4J2 configuration for each. On the other hand, Logback and Log4J2 are (almost completely) different libraries for the same purpose of logging.

Comment: But the [spring-boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration) says that it could control the log initialization.

`Because the standard logback.xml configuration file is loaded too early, you cannot use extensions in it. You need to either use logback-spring.xml or define a logging.config property.`

Comment: I've tried exactly that with Logback...and indeed it works, but the same doesn't apply for Log4J2.

Comment: If you can use Logback with async appenders, you can get some pretty decent performance — comparable with Log4J2. In that case, you would need LMAX Disruptor additionally in your classpath.

Comment: Aha, thanks for more information. Next time I'm going to try to use `logback` instead of `log4j2`. 
But should I open an issue to `spring-boot` or `log4j2`, I wonder?

Comment: Today this is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71248288/1251613

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-spring-boot</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).