# How to fall back to log4j2.xml when custom configurationFile is missing

Tags: log4j2

My environment : JBoss EAP 7 with a "log4j2.xml" in classpath (historic behavior).

I would like to introduce a way to have a (non mandatory) **custom log4j2 configuration file** (per EAR application) but still use (fall back) to (existing) "log4j2.xml" if the custom configuration file is missing.

To me, the only way to accomplish this was to use **composite configuration** by using "log4j2.configurationFile" property (within log4j2.component.properties) and set both the "log4j2.xml" and the custom configuration filename (separated by a comma).

**But if the custom file is missing, even the generic "log4j2.xml" is ignored**.

When looking at log4j2 (v2.12.1) code (https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/log4j-2.12.1/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationFactory.java#L380) I can see that indeed **if one config file is missing, none config file (of the list) is used** (-> "return null")

Is there a way to accomplish the behavior I want?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using Spring, profiles appear to support the behavior you want, [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559824/spring-profiles-different-log4j2-configs).

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen but I am not using Spring

Comment: Why not just tell your user to specify the system property `"log4j.configurationFile"` if they wish to override the provided configuration? See [configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) page of log4j2 manual. If that's not satisfactory then you could create a [custom ConfigurationFactory](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#ConfigurationFactory)

Comment: Thank you @D.B. for your comment. Maybe I was not clear enough. So I have edited my question saying I am using an application server that can be common to several application.
And for now all applications were using (by default) the "log4j2.xml" present in the classpath.